# Contain text within width boundary of div in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I contain the text to be within the width of my div and wrap to a new line in my css? Thank you!!

```
.render-message {
    margin-top: 8px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.render-message {
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="render-message">

  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry s standard dummy text ever since the when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
  not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially

</div>
```